# Landing on a Community Chest in Monopoly on your second turn?

Tags: probability

I know the probability of getting a community chest on a users first turn is 1/36, because that is the probability of rolling a sum of two with two dice, and the community chest is two spaces from the GO square, however, I'm not sure how I could calculate the 2nd turn's odds of landing on a community chest.

Comment: How many squares are there in a monopoly table?

Comment: @JimmyR. there are 40 squares.

Comment: Do cases: how many sequences of two turns land on Community Chest?  For instance, suppose it's 13 squares from Go to CC.  Then a 11 and 2 would get there, a 10 and 3, a 9 and 4 ...

Comment: Then the probability of reaching the chest square in the second run (you do not mean turn, right?, you mean the second time that you pass the GO square, right?) is equal to the probability of rolling a sum of exactly $42$ with as many dice as you want. Not impossible, but not trivial calculation.

Comment: @JimmyR. by second turn, I mean, if you landed on the first community chest with a sum of two, then other players take their turns, then it becomes your chance to roll after everyone else has. There is also 3 community chests, I'm not specifically talking about landing on one SPECIFIC chest, any chest counts.

Comment: This question is interesting enough that you are likely to get some answers, but you should really do the legwork yourself to make the problem self-contained.  Like: how many squares on the board?  How many Community Chest squares and where they are, etc.

Comment: But if the community chest is on square number 2. and there are 40 squares then there is no way to reach it in the second turn, right?

Comment: There are a lot of complications.  First of all, if you get a double on the first round you roll again...but of course you risk jail.  Even if you discount jail, you can certainly get quite far on the first move.  Then there's the chance (ahem) that you draw a card that moves you around.  I'd just sample it.

Comment: Don’t overlook the possibility of landing on **Chance** on your first turn, getting sent elsewhere by the card drawn, and then reaching a **Community Chest** square on your next turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The original, oversimplified post:**

There is zero probability of landing on the first community chest on your second turn, since you must move at *least* for squares from Go after two turns. It is also impossible to reach the third Community Chess on just two turns. The second community chest is between St. James Place and Tennessee Ave., seventeen squares from Go. The ways you can travel seventeen squares in two turns are:

- Roll a 12, then a 5.
- Roll an 11, then a 6.
- Roll a 10, then a 7.
- Roll a 9, then an 8.
- Roll a 8, then a 9.
- Roll a 7, then a 10.
- Roll a 6, then an 11.
- Roll a 5, then a 12.

The probability of rolling a 12 is $1/36$. The probability of rolling a 5 is $4/36$, so the probability of rolling a 12 and then a 5 is $$\frac{1}{36}\cdot\frac{4}{36}=\frac{4}{1296}.$$ Perform similar computations for all of the combinations, and then add them together.

**The new and improved post:**

The above is way too simple. It ignores rolling doubles, which allow the player to roll again on the same turn, and chance and community chest cards, which may send the player to different parts of the board. This gets very complicated very fast, but what is clear is that the naive calculation above is an underestimation of the probability of landing on a community chest square during on's second turn. To solve the problem in a more sophisticated way, I wrote a computer simulation. First, what is a turn? A turn ends when one of the following happens:

1. The player does not roll doubles.
2. The player lands in jail (not just visiting).

The player can land in jail for any of the following reasons:

1. The player rolls doubles three times in the same turn. In this case, he goes to jail immediately after his last roll.
2. He draws a card sending him to jail.
3. He lands on the go to jail square.

My simulation accounts for all 16 chance cards and 17 community chest cards. it also assumes that if a player goes to jail on his first turn, he will choose to get out (by paying $\$$50) on his second turn. By running the simulation in 100 batches of 1000 trials each, I can say that with $95\%$ confidence, the probability of landing on any community chest square at least once during your second turn is between $8.75\%$ and $9.06\%.$

Using the naive calculation above, the probability is estimated at $8.26\%$, which is lower than the measured probability, as expected.

Comment: I think you have ignored the possible effect of the Chance square.

Comment: @MatthewConroy please see my new edit for the complete analysis.

Comment: Nice work.  Simulation seems like a good way to go, since who needs this probability exactly anyway? Cheers!

Comment: Nice post, I wish I could see the actual mathematical calculations though of how you'd get 8.75% and 9.06%, It is complicated though since there are so many factors

Comment: @Xor No calculations. I just taught a computer how to play monopoly, and then had it play out the first two turns 100000 times, and saw what happened.

Comment: Thanks a lot, may I ask, what programming language did you use to preform this?

Comment: I used Mathematica.